# C++ how to append ifstream to read multiple files as one big file

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream

I have files that are broken into many smaller files. For example, I have

file1
file2
...
file10

file1 to file10 is just one file split into 10. Now I want to read these 10 files, and I want to avoid merging the 10 files together to create one big file due to the large size of the files. I want read them one after the other as if it is one big file.

This is what I have now, reading one file at a time.

```
std::ifstream file(filePath, std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
iostreams::filtering_istream input;
// check if the file is a .gz file by checking the file extension
if (filePath.compare(filePath.size() - 3, 3, ".gz") == 0)
{
  input.push(iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
}
input.push(file);
```

Is there a way to append multiple ifstreams in order to read multiple files one after the other as if they're one big file?

I would like to use ifstreams because every subsequent file (file 2 to 10) has 4 metadata lines that I want to skip.

Any help on how to append is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create vector of files, loop through them. I don't understand what is the difficulty you'r facing.

Answer (score -1):

This pseudo-code may help you.

```
int main()
{
    // Get files Names (e.g. data1.txt)
    std::vector<std::string> filesNames;

    for( i < filesNames.size() ){
        // Open File 
        // Check if it is opened successfully.
        // Read data via while() loop
        // Close File
    }

    return 0;
}
```